# Perl rename hangs when renaming files with regular expression

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I'm trying to use `perl-rename` on Arch Linux to rename many files according to a regex. I have a large amount of files in a folder that follow this format:

```
Title of File [Year] - quality.filetype
```

where "Year" is 4 digits, quality could be any of 720p, 1080p, DVD, etc., and filetype can be any of mp4, mkv, etc.

I'm trying to rename the files to follow this format:

```
[Year] Title of File (quality).filetype
```

I've developed this regular expression to match the relevant parts of the file:

```
/(.+) \[(\d{4})\](?: - (.+)\.+)*/
```

After doing some research I developed this command to try and do the rename (I'll remove `-n` once I know it will work):

```
perl-rename -n 's/(.+) \[(\d{4})\](?: - (.+)\.+)*/[$2] $1 ($3)./'
```

When I run this command, perl-rename outputs nothing and doesn't exit. Can anyone help me spot the mistake?

Comment: You don't appear to be giving it any filenames to work on?

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I read your comment I realized my mistake. Adding the asterisk prevents the command from hanging. Now just to figure out why the string replacement isn't working...

Comment: Why are you saying `\.+`?  That means one or more periods — when do you need to match that? Why are you putting an asterisk after the entire _`⁠ - quality`_ subexpression?  Do you expect to match that more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't specifying which files to rename. Added an asterisk to end of command:

```
perl-rename -n 's/(.+) \[(\d{4})\](?: - (.+)\.+)*/[$2] $1 ($3)./' *
```

Further, the way I was referencing capture groups was incorrect. Referencing capture groups is done like `\1`, `\2`, etc. rather than `$1`, `$2`, etc. The working expression looked like:

```
perl-rename -n 's/(.+) \[(\d{4})\](?: - (.+)\.+)*/[\2] \1 (\3)./' *
```